# How to replace current symbols with font awesome icons in every pager?

Tags: paging

I want to replace current symbols with font awesome icons in every pager on my site. Problem is, the icon tag is printing as text, not as html. Here's my code:

```
function default_preprocess_pager(&$vars, $hook) {
  if ($vars['quantity'] > 5) $vars['quantity'] = 5;
  $vars['tags'][0] = '<<';
  $vars['tags'][1] = '<';
  $vars['tags'][3] = '>';
  $vars['tags'][4] = '<i class="fa fa-arrow-double"></i>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [function theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7.x) you see this line:

```
 $li_last = theme('pager_last', array('text' => (isset($tags[4]) ? $tags[4] : t('last »')), 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));
```

which eventually leads you via [theme_pager_last](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_last/7.x) to [function theme_pager_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_link/7.x) which has this bit of code:

```
return '<a' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . check_plain($text) . '</a>';
```

where [check_plain](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7.x) is the function that converts html to text.

so you need to supply your own version of theme_pager_link. Look at this post and others for information on how to do that:

[How to override theme functions in Drupal 7](http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-override-theme-functions-drupal-7)